# Pyodbc connection giving strange error

Tags: python, teradata, pyodbc

I am getting strange error while trying to connect to Teradata from Python Pyodbc.

The code i used

```
import pyodbc
pyodbc.pooling=False
conn=pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ 
TeradataDriver16.20};DBCNAME=DBCNAME;UID=user_id;
PWD=Password;QUIETMODE=YES;database=databse;')
```

The above connection is successful.
Now I am trying to run the below query

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT TOP 10 * FROM DB_NAME")
tables = cursor.fetchall()
```

This results in following error

```
Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] 䑛瑡䑡物捥嵴佛䉄⁃楬嵢唠楮潣敤挠湯敶瑲牥戠晵敦\u2072
癯牥汦睯\x00\x000\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00[\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00 (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Any pointers in solving this would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen the Teradata instructions for pyodbc [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Unicode#teradata)?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot recreate your error with pyodbc. Could you try Teradata's own official package 'teradata' and see if you get similar behaviour.

```
pip install teradata
```

And then

```
import teradata

udaExec = teradata.UdaExec (appName="HelloWorld", version="1.0",
            logConsole=False)

with udaExec.connect(method="odbc",system=DBCNAME,  
                     driver="TeradataDriver16.20",
                     database=DBCNAME, username=user_id,
                     password=Password) as session: 
    for row in session.execute("SELECT TOP 10 * FROM DB_NAME"):
        print(row)
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. My issue is sorted out after installing unixodbc package.